# How Install jdk 8 in android in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, ubuntu-14.04

How can I **install** `jdk 1.8` in `android-studio` using the command line in **Ubuntu 14.04**?

After installation of `jdk 8` and its connect in `android-studio` it gives these errors in xml:

Image:-[image]

Image:-[image]

Comment: It is possible to install JDK 8 in Ubuntu 14.04, but I didn't get the part with the android and the command line.

Comment: asking for command to install jdk 8 into my android....

Comment: you cannot install JDK into an Android device. If this is your question, it is not possible at all.

Comment: Installing the jdk on your pc will also install it for android studio.

Comment: have look edit question .....

Comment: You need to start your IDE with the JRE/JDK 8 you already have installed. I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) link. Have a look at the "Linux" section.

Answer (score 0):

write following commond in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-kdk
```

Comment: this command install Java 1.8 into my PC. I wanted to installation for android-studio .... thanx for your response

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set what your default java version is. So that when the IDE (Android Studio) is loaded, it uses that one.

Take a look at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308663/how-to-set-the-default-java-version)